Apache Drill/Joda datetime library timezone conversion
I was using Apache Drill, which underneath use Joda library for anything date/time related, to convert time zone conversion. Based on the Joda documentation https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html, using timezone name (America/Los_Angeles) with formatter 'Z' should work fine.
But query select to_timestamp('2015-03-30 20:49:59.0 America/Los_Angeles', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s Z'); gives this error:
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2015-03-30 20:49:59.0 America/Los_Angeles" is malformed at "America/Los_Angeles"


Please, refer to logs for more information.

[Error Id: 40692837-2945-4b43-9632-56f5fd082197 on 161.44.254.114:31010]

I'm issuing SQL query from Apache Drill but internally Joda library is used for this datetime conversion... I've confirmed it in the source code and the IllegalArgumentException raised above is from Joda as well.
If I use timezone id e.g. -0500 or -05:00 instead of timezone name "America/Los_Angeles" then it works...
select to_timestamp('2015-03-30 20:49:59.0 -0500', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s Z');
2015-03-30T21:49

I'm working with microservices and through SQL and Apache Drill, so only the timezone name is exposed that I can use. There's no way for me to map timezone name to id in SQL/Apache Drill.
